# Insert event to google calendar nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm reading through the docs on inserting events in to the google calendar api but not having any success.  I was able to follow the quick start guide and pull a list of events from my google calendar but now I cant get the insert to work.  I've kept the enviroment set up the same and just added the insert method but My error is `There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Insufficent Permission`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
try {
  const content = fs.readFileSync('client_secret.json');
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
} catch (err) {
  return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 * @return {function} if error in reading credentials.json asks for a new one.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  let token = {};
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  try {
    token = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH);
  } catch (err) {
    return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
  }
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
  callback(oAuth2Client);
}
/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', code => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}



function insertEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
  var event = {
    summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
    location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    description: "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
    start: {
      dateTime: '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
      timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
      timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'],
    attendees: [{ email: 'lpage@example.com' }, { email: 'sbrin@example.com' }],
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [
        { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
        { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }
      ]
    }
  };

  calendar.events.insert(
    {
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event
    },
    function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(
          'There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err
        );
        return;
      }
      console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your scope is correct for using `calendar.events.insert()`. So how about this modification?

1. I thought that the scope might be not reflected to the access token yet. So please remove `credentials.json` once, and authorize the scopes again. By this, it creates `credentials.json` again. And the access token and refresh token reflected the scope can be retrieved.
2. In your script, `event.htmlLink` of `console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink)` becomes `undefined`. So in the case of your script, please modify to `console.log('Event created: %s', event.data.htmlLink)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please include SCOPE `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.event'`. This is required for working with calendar events.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
try {
  const content = fs.readFileSync('client_secret.json');
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
} catch (err) {
  return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 * @return {function} if error in reading credentials.json asks for a new one.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
  let token = {};
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  try {
    token = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH);
  } catch (err) {
    return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
  }
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
  callback(oAuth2Client);
}
/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', code => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}



function insertEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
  var event = {
    summary: 'Google I/O 2019',
    location: '800 Howard St.',
    description: "A chance to hear more.",
    start: {
      dateTime: '2019-11-28T09:00:00-07:00',
      timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: '2019-11-28T10:00:00-07:00',
      timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    recurrence: ['RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'],
    attendees: [{ email: 'lpage@example.com' }, { email: 'sbrin@example.com' }],
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [
        { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
        { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 }
      ]
    }
  };

  calendar.events.insert(
    {
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event
    },
    function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(
          'There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err
        );
        return;
      }
      console.log('Event created: %s', event.data.htmlLink);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: after you run node . authorize this app by visiting the url and paste the code, event will be created

Comment: Adding an explanation to the post would be helpful.

Comment: Can anyone help me with deleting an event from google calendar node js @zmag

Comment: Need to send an ***instantaneous email*** to the _attendees_ in the above code, any help is appreciated. ( Currently attendees are getting it one day before the event )

Comment: Nobody needs to input Gmail credentials in a terminal. It only matters if it's code you can run on a backend and frontend server