# Google Calendar API - How to insert new event using NodeJS REST API

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api

I would like to send data to my NodeJS backend (Express framework) and then create an event on Google Calendar using Google Calendar API.

I'm receiving data using the POST method come form express.Router()

At this moment if I send a request using Postman I have received an error: "There was an error contacting the Calendar service: Error: Login Required"

My question is how to call insertEvent() method inside the post method body and pass data received from the user?

A similar situation is described in this post [Insert event to google calendar nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807375/insert-event-to-google-calendar-nodejs) but the data are hard-coded.

My full code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const myEvents = [];

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Calendar API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      myEvents.push(events);
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}


function insertEvents(event, auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
  var event = event;
  calendar.events.insert(
    {
      auth: auth,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event
    },
    function(err, event) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(
          'There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err
        );
        return;
      }
      console.log('Event created: %s', event.data.htmlLink);
    }
  );
}


/* GET events listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(myEvents);
});

/* Create a new event. */
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
  let newEvent = req.body;
  insertEvents(newEvent, auth); //how to pass req.body and auth?
  res.send('Ok');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you need to save the refresh_token for each user in db for connecting to google-calendar in future use**

```
const secrets = {
  client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirect_uris: process.env.REDIRECT_URIS,
};

const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

const {
  client_id,
  client_secret,
  redirect_uris
} = secrets;

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris);
```

**// pass userId,and newEvent Object in the req.body**

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res, next)=>{
  const {id,newEvent} = req.body;

  //find User RefreshToken Using id from db
  //something like below
  const {refresh_token} = await db.user.findById(id)

  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token});

  await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId:'primary',
      resource: newEvent
    })
  res.send('Ok');
});
```

Comment: OP could you confirm if this has solved your problem? Looking at the code this should solve your question.

Comment: I think it may be useful to create a new Google Calendar event, but in my case, I don't use any database and I don't store any users' data. To be honest I've solved my problem (it's a temporary solution) by putting all the above methods ( fs.readFile(), authorize(), getAccessToken() ) inside router.post() method. Thanks to that the auth object is available and I'm able to create a new event with user's data. But I'm not going to show my solution because it is... "spaghetti code" - firstly, I need to refactor it or find a new solution.